# How to detect the date format? (python)

Tags: python, date, automation

I have a Dataframe in python, with the data coming from a csv.
In the column "Date" I have a date (:)) but I don't know the date format. How can I detect it?

e.g.: I can have 05/05/2022. this can be M/D/Y or D/M/Y. I can manually understand it by looking at other entries, but I wish I can do it automatically.

Is there a way to do so?
thank you

datetime.strptime requires you to know the format.
trying (try - exept)-commands isn't good since there are so many different format I can receive.

it would be nice to have something that recognizes the format...

Update:
Thank you for the first answers, but the output I would like to have is THE FORMAT of the date that is used in the column.
Knowing also the fact that the format is unique within each column

Comment: Perhaps the issue is with the source data provider.  Is it possible to request clean data from the provider; or for the provider to sanitise their data first?

Comment: Yes, the issue is EXACTLY the provider, who is incompetent :) I cannot trust him at all, nor replace him. Hence my problem :)

Comment: Do you have an example ?
Something like that ?
Input "08/11/2022" -> Output "%d/%m/%Y"

Comment: Precisely liker that. Usually the inputs can be 1/12/2022 or 12/1/2022 or 1-12-2022 or 12-1-2022. I would like an output like "%d%m%Y" or "%m%d%Y" etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can try the [dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) library.
To deal with dates and also with the diversity of timezones people often use external libraries such as `pytz` or `dateutil`.

`dateutil` has a very powerful parser.

```py
from dateutil.parser import parse

parse('05/05/2022')  # datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 5, 0, 0)
parse('2022-05-05')  # datetime.datetime(2022, 5, 5, 0, 0)
```

Comment: thank you, I edited the question cause it was not clear.

Answer (score 0):

Use the isinstance built-in function to check if a variable is a datetime object in Python, e.g. if isinstance(today, datetime): . The isinstance function returns True if the passed in object is an instance or a subclass of the passed in class. Copied!20-Apr-2022

check out here

https://www.folkstalk.com/2022/10/python-check-if-string-is-date-format-with-code-examples.html